# Issue with using an object created via reflection

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I am trying to write a program that can be used to send messages to a set of subscribers. The subscribers and technology used to deliver the messages is not important. The message types are defined by an XML schema and are implemented as a Java API. There is an abstract super-type that all message types extend. The API defines static methods to allow for conversion between XML and Java and vice versa (`fromXML()` and `toXML()`).

I am having difficulties implementing this. I have included a sample of the code I am trying to get to work below. It does not compile as written. The abstract super-type is the `MessageType` class and my plan is to pass in the name of the "real" message type and have this code create the necessary objects to do what is needed to send a message of the specified sub-type.

```
public class Writer {

  public static void runExample(String[] args) throws Exception {
    UUID serviceID = UUID.fromString(args[1]);

    ServiceBus bus = ServiceBus.getServiceBus();
    bus.init(serviceID);

    // The intention is to pass the message type name so that this code can be used for any
    // "message" type.
    String msgName = args[0];

    // Get the message type class from the passed name.
    Class<? extends MessageType> msgClass = (Class<? extends MessageType>) Class.forName(msgName);

    // Create a writer for the specified message type.
    MessageWriter<? extends MessageType> writer = bus.createWriter(msgName, msgClass);

    // Read in some XML content from a file.
    String xml = loadMsg(args[2]);

    // Want to do something like this:
    msgClass object = msgClass.fromXML(xml);
    // Of course, this does not compile. Is there a way to do this?

    // Create a java object of the message type from the XML read in.
    MessageType object = MessageType.fromXML(xml);

    // With the line above the statement below fails to compile with the error:
    //   The method write(capture#4-of ? extends MessageType) in the type
    //   MessageWriter<capture#4-of ? extends MessageType> is not applicable for
    //   the arguments (MessageType)

    writer.write(object);
  }

  private static String loadMsg(String fileName) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(fileName)));
    String line = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    do {
    line = reader.readLine();
    if (line != null)
      sb.append(line);
    } while (line != null);

    reader.close();
    return sb.toString();
  }

}
```

Does anyone know if it's possible to do what I've described above?

Comment: What is the compile error? Don't make us copy the whole thing into an IDE for find out.

Comment: The error message is included in the code as a comment.

Comment: You might want to point it out a bit better. It is not like that is the only comment in your code.

Comment: Gee, I thought comments were helpful.

Comment: post a lot of code and people are going to skim. We assume the comments were copied from your code not put as part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `Writer` is `MessageWriter<? extends MessageType>`, this mean it could be any `MessageWriter` that takes a subclass of `MessageType`. So the actual instance could be `MessageWriter<MySuperMessageType>`. Since your `MessageType` instance cannot be confirmed by the compiler to be `MySuperMessageType`, the compiler fails it.

If the writer was of type `MessageWriter<MessageType>` or `MessageWritier<? super MessageType>` it would work. The other option is to create a generic method...

```
private <T extends MessageType> myMethod(Class<T> type){
   MessageWriter<T> writer = bus.createWriter(msgName, msgClass);
   String xml = loadMsg(args[2]);
   // you could use reflection to get the public static methods from the class instance
   // msgClass object = msgClass.fromXML(xml);
   T object = (T) MessageType.fromXML(xml);
   writer.write(object);
}
```

Comment: Looked like it was going to work at first, but then ...
Here's my code:

    private <T extends MessageType> void write(Class<T> type, String topic, String content) throws UCIException,
      IOException {
      MessageWriter<T> writer = bus.createWriter(topic, type);
      T object = (T) MessageType.fromXML(content);
      writer.write(object);
    }

Unfortunately, I get a run-time error:
(to be continued)

Comment: Exception in thread "main" uci.UCIException: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: Unable to create an instance of uci.types.MessageType
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.InstantiationException]
 at uci.types.MessageType.fromXML(MessageType.java:535)
 at uci.types.MessageType.fromXML(MessageType.java:571)
 at boeingfuzz.Sender.write(Sender.java:34)
 at boeingfuzz.Sender.send(Sender.java:28)
 at boeingfuzz.Main.main(Main.java:24)

Comment: Sigh ... As an aside, how do I enter a comment that doesn't lose its formatting?